# Pubsub implementation with jaxl library

Tags: php, bots, publish-subscribe

I am using jaxl library for bot development on my debian server with openfire.

Now i want to apply pubsub functionality to it.

My scenario is : user subscribes to an event & when an event occurs message is sent to all the subscribers.

I am confused how to implement pubsub through im.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need some kind of persistent message store. Apache's ActiveMQ and the STOMP protocol would be pretty easy to implement from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, anyways here is the solution.

Movim.eu project which uses jaxl php library as base for all xmpp interactions have already implemented/tested/deployed pubsub and microblogging functionalities inside Movim code base using Jaxl library. You can try out their code base which will contain even some sample examples of how pubsub can be achieved using Jaxl library.